# How to go about solving this (Design patterns)

Tags: design-patterns

I have a billing system in which different type of customers have different type of discount schemes. And for a given bill, a net payable amount should be generated based on the type of the customer and the product.

And there are few rules too. Like :

•If the user is an employee of the store, he gets a 30% discount

•If the user is an affiliate of the store, he gets a 10% discount

•If the user has been a customer for over 2 years, he gets a 5% discount.

•For every $100 on the bill, there would be a $ 5 discount (e.g. for $ 990, you get $ 45 as a discount).

•The percentage based discounts do not apply on groceries
...

I had few Ideas in my mind. 1st bet is to think about a decorator pattern :

```
Customer <<Interface>>     

|                       
CustomerImpl  



DiscountDecorator <<AbstractClass>> imp Customer

 |             |            |           |
AffiDiscount   StoreEmp   OverTwoYears   AnyOtherDisc
               Discount     Discount       Discount
Items  { 
//? ? :/
}
```

But then the `Discounts` are dependent on `Items` as well.

What are my options?

- extend `Customer` Interface with an `Item` Interface to keep track on type of item?
- Pass `List` of `Items` to the discount classes.
  ...
  How to properly have co-relation with `Customer` and `Item` classes so that I can decorate them together?

Comment: @Downvoter Please mention your reasons for the down-vote so that the question can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't see a need for a pattern yet, maybe just do something like this:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
public class So35680415 {
    enum Discount {
        employee {
            @Override double discount(double amount) {
                return amount*.30;
            };
        },
        affiliate {
            @Override double discount(double amount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return amount*.10;
            };
        },
        customerForTwoYears {
            @Override double discount(double amount) {
                return Math.floor(amount/100)*100*.05;
            };
        };
        abstract double discount(double amount);
    }
    static class User {
        void discounts(double amount) {
            for(Discount discount:discounts)
                System.out.println("discount for: "+discount+" on: $"+amount+" is: $"+discount.discount(amount));
        }
        EnumSet<Discount> discounts=EnumSet.noneOf(Discount.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user=new User();
        user.discounts.add(Discount.employee);
        user.discounts(100);
        System.out.println("---");
        user.discounts.add(Discount.affiliate);
        user.discounts(100);
        System.out.println("---");
        user.discounts.add(Discount.customerForTwoYears);
        user.discounts(100);
        System.out.println("---");
    }
}
```

edit to answer questions: it does not seem to violate srp as it does one thing namely compute a discount. enums seem ideal for the task. the types of enums *are* subclasses. adding another enum is easy. it does sorta look like the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: Have few questions : 1) Doesn't it violates SRP ? 2) Should Enum's be assigned such a task? Aren't the types in the Enum 's are eligible to be a sub-class?And what if there are additions of discounts in future ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use the decorator pattern (unless there's more to this problem then I understand). Simple polymorphism can do the trick.

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomer implements Customer {

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    protected abstract double priceDiscountedPercentage(Item item);

    private double priceDiscounted(double bill) {
        return (bill - (Math.floor(bill / 100) * 5));
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public double ringUp() {
        double bill = 0;
        for(Item item : items) {
            if(!item.isGrocery()) {
                bill += priceDiscountedPercentage(item);
            } else {
                bill += item.getPrice();
            }
        }
        return priceDiscounted(bill);
    }
}
```

Then you'd have the different customer classes for example:

```
public class Employee extends AbstractCustomer implements Customer {
    @Override
    protected double priceDiscountedPercentage(Item item) {
        return (item.getPrice() * 0.7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `Employee` class has to implement `Customer` too?

Comment: It doesn't (at least not in Java in which this example is given), but I like to be explicit about interface inheritance if it's not too cumbersome.